# Plotting evolution of probability with time

Tags: plotting, graphics, data, histograms

I have compiled data about the evolution of a function with time and the data looks something like this.

[image]

I wanted to plot this data in the form of a density histogram such that every row represents one of the four states and every column represented number the observances of the object in one of the four states at a particular time. The end result should appear something like.[image]

I first tried to use the DensityHistorgram but I was unable to put discrete data into it and the documentation did not mention how I could do so. I would be very grateful if anyone could tell me how to plot such a function.

Note: I apologize for putting the data as an image. If you can plot it for any simple data I could use that forward in my work. So, please feel free to use the simplest of data. I only wish to understand how data can be plotted in this manner.

Comment: tried `MatrixPlot`?

Comment: May you paste the data as code instead of an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MatrixPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html):

```
data = Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {4, 20}];

MatrixPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/4,  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]