# Heatmap plot of probability distribution evolution at discrete time intervals?

Tags: plotting

In the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198806/plotting-evolution-of-probability-with-time) it is suggested to use `MatrixPlot` to obtain a heatmap plot of a time evolving probability distribution. However, what if my probability distribution is given by

```
distribution = SmoothKernelDistribution[data]
```

obtained from `data` that is updated at every time step. And ideally I would like to have a heatmap over the values of

```
PDF[distribution, y]
```

such that the y-axis is labeled by the different `y` values, instead of just `1,2,3,4,...` as in the `MatrixPlot` example.

> Is there a way to achieve a (ideally continuous, but discrete also works) heatmap plot with appropriate y-axis scaling and discrete (ideally interpolated, but rough jumps in color also ok) x-axis steps in Mathematica?

Example, of how it might look like (not y-axis continuous, and not x-axis interpolated):

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a task for `DensityPlot`. (`MatrixPlot` or `ArrayPlot` can be used of course, one just need to adjust the `FrameTicks` option a bit. ) Which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the suggestions! I'll give these a try.